# Get Image from APi

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I'm trying to implement this code for making API call for image without success:

```
 <kit-general-16 [isNew]="product.isNew" [isFavorite]="product.isFavorite" [image]="mainImage(product.productImage)"
        [name]="product.title" [price]="product.price" [oldPrice]="product.oldPrice" routerLink="../edit-product/{{product.id}}"></kit-general-16>
    </div>
```

Component:

```
mainImage(productImage: number) {
    this.productService.getProductImage(productImage);
  }
```

Service:

```
getProductImage(imageId) {
    return this.http.get<any>(environment.apiKey + '/engine/product/files/' + imageId)
  }
```

When I use it this way:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6" *ngFor="let product of products">
      <kit-general-16 [isNew]="product.isNew" [isFavorite]="product.isFavorite" image="http://123.123.122.1:8090/engine/product/files/{{product.productImage}}"
        [name]="product.title" [price]="product.price" [oldPrice]="product.oldPrice" routerLink="../edit-product/{{product.id}}"></kit-general-16>
    </div>
```

It's working fine.
Do you know where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service function `getProductImage` is returning an `Observable`, therefore you'll need to add [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to your `image` @input param, like this:

```
<kit-general-16 [isNew]="product.isNew" [isFavorite]="product.isFavorite" [image]="mainImage(product.productImage) | async"
    [name]="product.title" [price]="product.price" [oldPrice]="product.oldPrice" routerLink="../edit-product/{{product.id}}"></kit-general-16>
</div>
```